# no instance of overloaded function matches argument list C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just have a very basic class that gives with functions that return the winning team of a match.

here's team.cpp

```
class teams
{
string teamName;
string teamName2;
int score;
int score2;

public:
teams ();
void set_team1();
void set_team2();
string get_score()
{
    if (score > score2)
    {
        return teamName;
    }
    else
    {
        return teamName2;
    }
}

private:
void teams::set_team1(string teamName, int score)
{
    this->teamName=teamName;
    this->score=score;
}
void teams::set_team2(string teamName2, int score2)
{
    this->teamName2=teamName2;
    this->score2=score2;
}
};
```

and here's is the line where i'm getting the error in the main method. I'm trying to create a teams object.

```
    firstTeam.set_team1(teamName, score);
    firstTeam.set_team2(teamName2, score2);
```

Visual studio comes up and says "error: no instance of overloaded function "team::set_team1" matches the argument list".

What am I missing?

This is the exact error I get:

```
1>c:\users\lab8.cpp(31): error C2664: 'void teams::set_team1(std::string,int)' : cannot     convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::string'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this     conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\lab8.cpp(32): error C2664: 'void teams::set_team2(std::string,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::string'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this     conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide a complete, minimal program that demonstrates your problem. Get rid of everything that isn't broken, then copy-paste what's left. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Can you give the exact message from Visual Studio? This looks like homework.

Comment: yes its homework, but i'm only asking for help on a specific problem. I posted the error message in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

> error C2664: 'void teams::set_team1(std::string,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::string'

From the error message, it is clear that first parameter isn't of type `std::string`. It is actually a `std::vector`. So,

```
 firstTeam.set_team1(teamName, score);  // Check what is the type of teamName
```

If you can see that `teamName` is actually a `std::string`, then check whether you are compiling the right file. Save the file and try again because the code you posted and the error message has no relation.

---

Compiler don't provide default constructor( constructor with no arguments ) in case your class overloads the constructor.

```
class teams
{
    string teamName;
    string teamName2;
    int score;
    int score2;

    // ...

    public:
       teams( string t, int s ) : teamName(x), score(s)
                               // Initializer list
       {}
};
```

But the I don't understand, why you have `teamName2`, `score2` members as members of teams. What if there are 10 teams? Just have an instance for each team and compare them with other instances of teams.

Comment: thank you. that was the problem. Both teamName and score were vectors.

Comment: Now I get this: 1>lab8.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall teams::teams(void)" (??0teams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\samuelrm\Desktop\lab8\lab8\lab8\Debug\lab8.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"
any ideas what that means?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is different type from `std::string`.

Comment: You forgot to provide the definition for the default constructor. You just provided the declaration for the constructor(`teams::teams()`) as a part of class declaration and linker couldn't find the definition for constructor while class instantiation, which linker is complaining about.

Comment: I thought the default constructor for any class was teams();
so I would have to have something like teams (string teamName, int score) right?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the two methods without parameters. Convert:

```
void set_team1();
void set_team2();
```

into:

```
void set_team1(string, int);
void set_team2(string, int);
```